# Yii2 SwiftMailer not sending email via default mail() function

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer, yii2-advanced-app

Following are my Configurations:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_MailTransport',
            ],
            'useFileTransport' => False,
        ],
```

I have even tried with followings:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'viewPath' => '@common/mail',
            'useFileTransport' => False,
        ],
```

I'm using following code to send email:

```
var_dump(\Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
                    ->setTo($email)
                    ->setFrom(\Yii::$app->params['supportEmail'])
                    ->setSubject('Message subject')
                    ->setTextBody('Plain text content')
                    ->setHtmlBody('<b>HTML content</b>')
                    ->send());
```

But its returning false everytime no exception is thrown.

I have used mail() function to send email for same content, its working fine and email is instant. But issue is only with the SwiftMailer.

I couldn't find way to debug it. I have Yii2Debugger enabled, but I can't fine any info in that as well.

**Edit:**

I Tried with Gmail SMTP, I'm getting

```
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [Connection timed out #110]
```

I tried their default `SMTP`, I'm not getting any error with that, but still getting false for it.

> We are on Sharing hosting env. DO I need to check any PHP Settings.

Comment: Probably not related by `Swift_MailTransport` is now insecure, use `Swift_SendmailTransport` instead.

Answer (score -2):

try this configuration

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'useFileTransport'=>false,
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.

            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                'username' => 'yourmail@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'yourpassword',
                'port' => '465',
                'encryption' => 'ssl',
            ],
        ],
```

hope it helps :)

Comment: I want to configure it with default mail() function rather then smtp.